# OpenCMS Publish Permission

Tags: html, acl, user-permissions, opencms

I am using OpenCMS 10.

1) I have created a new user lets say mkumar.

2) I assigned *Users* group to the user.

3) I assigned *Element author* role ([having least permissions](http://documentation.opencms.org/opencms-documentation/background/permissions-in-opencms/users-groups-roles-and-ous/roles-in-opencms/))

> **Element Author**
>
> An element author can only access the page editor (and content editors). This role can create, add and edit content elements.

4) Now I created new resource/page say myPage.html and I add a sample content in it.

5) I set permission of mkumar on myPage.html [Check image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLca3.png)

6) (From another browser) mkumar logged in and open myPage.html. He edited the content (say he add more content).

7) After editing mkumar is able to publish (but in permission box is ***denied Direct Publish***).

**Problem:**

I want to remove publish permission. What should I do now?

Answer (score 0):

You can set permission for

```
direct_publish.jsp
publish.jsp
publish_project.jsp
```

under folder :

/system/modules/org.opencms.ade.publish/

or you can edit project and assign permission
[assign permission](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSIeV.png)

Comment: but, for button on ade toolbar i can disable it

Answer (score 0):

OpenCms uses containerpages to show contents from different content elements.
A containerpage is the page which is called in the browser.
Containerpages represent you page structure e.g.

```
 -folder1
  --index.html (containerpage)
 -folder2
  --index.html (containerpage)
  --folder2.1
   ---index.html (containerpage)
 -folder3
  --index.html (containerpage)
```

The content elements are not stored in this page structure. 
They are stored in a folder called `.content`. This folder is always placed in a special folder called `subsitemap`. The folder `sites/default` is a `subsitemap` by default.
Each resource type has its own subfolder.

So if you set permissions, you always have to set them on the subfolders of the folder `.content`.

So a complete folder structure could look like.

```
 -.content
  --contentelementfolder1 
   ---contentelement1.xml 
   ---contentelement2.xml 
  --contentelementfolder2 
   ---contentelement1.xml 
   ---contentelement2.xml 
  --.config (configuration file for this subsitemap) 
 -folder1
  --index.html (containerpage)
 -folder2
  --index.html (containerpage)
  --folder2.1
   ---index.html (containerpage)
 -folder3
  --index.html (containerpage)
```

By the way, you do not have to deny write permission if you want a user to not be able to edit a file. It is enough to NOT tick the `allowed` checkbox.